# Passing parameters from trinidad controls to the flow

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc, spring, spring-webflow, trinidad

I am new to JSF, Facelets, SWF and Trinidad technologies, and I having a problem submitting parameters from the `<tr:commandButton>` on a xhtml page to the flow (using the `<f:param>`). The interesting thing is when I use `<h:commanButton>` instead of the `<tr:commandButton>`, everything works fine. The reason I need to use trinidad button is that I have to put it in `<tr:forms>` to support PPR.

I really appreciate your helps.

Comment: are you sure the tags related to spring are required? And the SWF one?

Comment: and - give more details as of where are you submitting to, what is your setup. And some code could be also useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<f:param>` didn't work in `<h:commandButton>` for long until JSF 2.0. It was intented to be used in combination with `<h:outputFormat>`, `<h:commandLink>` and `<h:outputLink>` only.

It look like that you're using JSF 2.0, but that Trinidad isn't "JSF 2.0 ready" yet. You should then use `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` instead.

Here's an example:

```
<tr:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.someProperty}" value="someValue" />
</tr:commandButton>
```

You can also consider upgrading Trinidad to a JSF 2.0 compatible version, if any available.